# Query execution takes long time when doing aggregate operations in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to generate a report using a query which have aggregate functions involved.

The query execution takes long time (more than a hour) and it haven't completed its execution even for one time.

Here is the query.

```
SELECT  ope,ffp,Sum(ACC_APPROVED_GOLD) ACC_APPROVED_GOLD,Sum(ACC_APPROVED_SILVER) ACC_APPROVED_SILVER,Sum(ACC_APPROVED_MISC) ACC_APPROVED_MISC,
  Sum(RET_APPROVED_GOLD) RET_APPROVED_GOLD,Sum(RET_APPROVED_SILVER)  RET_APPROVED_SILVER,Sum(RET_APPROVED_MISC) RET_APPROVED_MISC
  FROM
  (
  SELECT
  ffpprogram FFP,OPERATINGAIRLINECODE OPE,
  CASE WHEN (ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS IN ('01','03') AND tier_level =1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACC_APPROVED_GOLD,
  CASE WHEN (ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS IN ('01','03') AND tier_level =2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACC_APPROVED_SILVER,
  CASE WHEN (ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS IN ('01','03') AND tier_level IS NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ACC_APPROVED_MISC,
  0 AS RET_APPROVED_GOLD,0 AS RET_APPROVED_SILVER, 0 AS RET_APPROVED_MISC
  FROM

  (SELECT  ffpprogram ,OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS,
   CASE WHEN  (prof.tierlevel IS NULL AND ffpprogram = 'SK') THEN
   (SELECT Nvl(tierlevel,0) FROM pcd_profile WHERE SubStr(FFPNUMBER,4) = resp.FFPMEMBERNUMBER AND airlinecode=resp.ffpprogram AND actioncode<> 'D')
   ELSE prof.tierlevel END tier_level
   FROM
  (
  (SELECT b.ffpprogram,b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,B.ACCRUALPOSTINGSTATUS,b.FFPMEMBERNUMBER
  FROM PAI_FILE A , PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL B,
  (SELECT DISTINCT c.TRANSACTIONID,d.received_date FROM pai_valid_accrual c, pai_file d
  WHERE Trunc(d.RECEIVED_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE('2015/01/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  and d.filetype=1 AND c.file_id=d.file_id AND c.TRANSACTIONID IS NOT NULL  )  req
  WHERE A.FILE_ID = B.FILE_ID
  AND a.filetype=2 AND  b.TRANSACTIONID = req.TRANSACTIONID
  AND a.received_date - req.received_date <=10
  AND Trunc(a.received_date) >= TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  ) resp
  left OUTER JOIN pcd_profile prof ON
  prof.FFPNUMBER = resp.FFPMEMBERNUMBER
  AND prof.airlinecode = resp.ffpprogram
  AND prof.actioncode<> 'D'
  ))

  UNION ALL

   SELECT
  ffpprogram FFP,OPERATINGAIRLINECODE OPE,
  0 AS ACC_APPROVED_GOLD,0 AS ACC_APPROVED_SILVER, 0 AS ACC_APPROVED_MISC,
  CASE WHEN (retroaccrualauthorization IN ('01','03') AND tier_level =1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RET_APPROVED_GOLD,
  CASE WHEN (retroaccrualauthorization IN ('01','03') AND tier_level =2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RET_APPROVED_SILVER,
  CASE WHEN (retroaccrualauthorization IN ('01','03') AND tier_level IS NULL ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END RET_APPROVED_MISC
  FROM
  (SELECT  ffpprogram ,OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,retroaccrualauthorization,
   CASE WHEN  (prof.tierlevel IS NULL AND ffpprogram = 'SK') THEN
   (SELECT Nvl(tierlevel,0) FROM pcd_profile WHERE SubStr(FFPNUMBER,4) = resp.FFPMEMBERNUMBER AND airlinecode=resp.ffpprogram AND actioncode<> 'D')
   ELSE prof.tierlevel END tier_level
   FROM
   (
  (SELECT b.ffpprogram,b.OPERATINGAIRLINECODE,B.retroaccrualauthorization,b.FFPMEMBERNUMBER
  FROM PAI_FILE A , PAI_VALID_retro B,
  (SELECT DISTINCT c.TRANSACTIONID,d.received_date FROM pai_valid_retro c, pai_file d
  WHERE Trunc(d.RECEIVED_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE('2015/01/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  and d.filetype=3 AND c.file_id=d.file_id ) req
  WHERE  a.file_id=b.file_id AND a.filetype=4 AND b.TRANSACTIONID = req.TRANSACTIONID
  AND a.received_date -     req.received_date <=10
  AND Trunc(a.received_date) >= TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  ) resp
  left OUTER JOIN pcd_profile prof ON
  prof.FFPNUMBER = resp.FFPMEMBERNUMBER
  AND prof.airlinecode = resp.ffpprogram
  AND prof.actioncode<> 'D'
  ))
  ) GROUP BY ope,ffp
  ;
```

However,when the aggregate functions are removed(i.e the outer select query) then the execution completes in 30 seconds.

I have checked the explain plan for the query with and with out aggregate function.

Here is the explain plan.

**with aggregate function:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                   |     3 |    72 |   157K  (1)| 00:31:31 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                    |                   |     3 |    72 |   157K  (1)| 00:31:31 |
|   2 |   VIEW                            |                   |     3 |    72 |   157K  (1)| 00:31:31 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL                      |                   |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PCD_PROFILE       |     2 |    40 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | SYS_C0011841      |  4069 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                   |     2 |   216 |   136K  (1)| 00:27:20 |
|*  7 |      HASH JOIN                    |                   |     2 |   176 |   136K  (1)| 00:27:20 |
|*  8 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PAI_FILE          |   438 |  5694 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   9 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                   |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |        NESTED LOOPS               |                   | 13836 |  1013K|   136K  (1)| 00:27:17 |
|  11 |         VIEW                      |                   |  7697 |   210K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|  12 |          HASH UNIQUE              |                   |  7697 |   293K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|* 13 |           HASH JOIN               |                   |  7697 |   293K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|* 14 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PAI_FILE          |    22 |   286 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 15 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | ACCRUAL_IDX7      |    58M|  1452M|   112K  (1)| 00:22:33 |
|* 16 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN          | ACCRUAL_IDX7      |     2 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL |     2 |    94 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PCD_PROFILE       |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SYS_C0011841      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 20 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PCD_PROFILE       |     2 |    40 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | SYS_C0011841      |  4069 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                   |     1 |   110 | 20901   (1)| 00:04:11 |
|* 23 |      HASH JOIN                    |                   |     1 |    90 | 20898   (1)| 00:04:11 |
|* 24 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PAI_FILE          |   438 |  5694 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|  25 |       NESTED LOOPS                |                   |       |       |            |          |
|  26 |        NESTED LOOPS               |                   |  2089 |   157K| 20692   (1)| 00:04:09 |
|  27 |         VIEW                      |                   |  1201 | 34829 | 17071   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  28 |          HASH UNIQUE              |                   |  1201 | 48040 | 17071   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|* 29 |           HASH JOIN               |                   |  1201 | 48040 | 17070   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|* 30 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PAI_FILE          |    22 |   286 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|  31 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | RETRO7_IDX        |  8205K|   211M| 16825   (1)| 00:03:22 |
|* 32 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RETRO7_IDX        |     2 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PAI_VALID_RETRO   |     2 |    96 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PCD_PROFILE       |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 35 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SYS_C0011841      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**with out aggregate function:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |                   |     3 |   326 |   157K (14)| 00:31:31 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                      |                   |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PCD_PROFILE       |     2 |    40 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | SYS_C0011841      |  4069 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                   |     2 |   216 |   136K  (1)| 00:27:20 |
|*  5 |    HASH JOIN                    |                   |     2 |   176 |   136K  (1)| 00:27:20 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PAI_FILE          |   438 |  5694 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|   7 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |      NESTED LOOPS               |                   | 13836 |  1013K|   136K  (1)| 00:27:17 |
|   9 |       VIEW                      |                   |  7697 |   210K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|  10 |        HASH UNIQUE              |                   |  7697 |   293K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|* 11 |         HASH JOIN               |                   |  7697 |   293K|   113K  (1)| 00:22:39 |
|* 12 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PAI_FILE          |    22 |   286 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|* 13 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | ACCRUAL_IDX7      |    58M|  1452M|   112K  (1)| 00:22:33 |
|* 14 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | ACCRUAL_IDX7      |     2 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PAI_VALID_ACCRUAL |     2 |    94 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PCD_PROFILE       |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 17 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SYS_C0011841      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | PCD_PROFILE       |     2 |    40 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN             | SYS_C0011841      |  4069 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER            |                   |     1 |   110 | 20901   (1)| 00:04:11 |
|* 21 |    HASH JOIN                    |                   |     1 |    90 | 20898   (1)| 00:04:11 |
|* 22 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL           | PAI_FILE          |   438 |  5694 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|  23 |     NESTED LOOPS                |                   |       |       |            |          |
|  24 |      NESTED LOOPS               |                   |  2089 |   157K| 20692   (1)| 00:04:09 |
|  25 |       VIEW                      |                   |  1201 | 34829 | 17071   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|  26 |        HASH UNIQUE              |                   |  1201 | 48040 | 17071   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|* 27 |         HASH JOIN               |                   |  1201 | 48040 | 17070   (1)| 00:03:25 |
|* 28 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL      | PAI_FILE          |    22 |   286 |   206   (1)| 00:00:03 |
|  29 |          INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | RETRO7_IDX        |  8205K|   211M| 16825   (1)| 00:03:22 |
|* 30 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RETRO7_IDX        |     2 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PAI_VALID_RETRO   |     2 |    96 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 32 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | PCD_PROFILE       |     1 |    20 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SYS_C0011841      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On comparing the explain plans, difference i have observed is the additional '*hash group by*' operation in the explain plan for the query which have aggregate function.

I couldn't get the exact reason why the *hash group by* operation is making the query execution time to be very high.

Any suggestions please..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The estimated time is `00:31:31` but you say the query actually takes more than an hour. Are the stats gathered up to date? The optimizer estimates just 3 rows, how many does the query actually return?

Comment: When you run the non-aggregating query, how many rows does it produce?

Comment: @ Lalit. Yes the stats are up to date for the tables used in the query. With aggregate function, i didn't get the exact result yet. but it should return some 500+ records.

Comment: @ Dave. I'm trying to get the count(*) of the records with out aggregate function.But its too, taking quite long time. Roughly it will be some 5 million records.

Comment: So without the aggregate it took 30s to get the first set of data - how many rows depends on your client's settings. That doesn't mean the query had completed, just that it had found enough rows to show you some. With the aggregates it has to retrieve all rows into memory before it can calculate them and show you anything. It would take you just as long (or longer) to get the entire result set back without the aggregates.

Comment: @Alex. Thanks for pointing this out. With out aggregate functions applied,query execution didn't complete as it seems to be. So the problem is with the query used overall not with the `hash group by` alone as i thought.

Comment: It might help to find out which operation is taking the most time.  You can find that information a query like this: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'your_sql_id', type => 'text') from dual;`

Comment: @JonHeller. Sure. will check this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely convoluted query to read from only four tables. I'm sure it can be greatly simplified as it seems to the the same code just with hardcoded checks for filetype. In the meantime, are a few things you could look into.

There are a couple of places where you have

```
WHERE Trunc(d.RECEIVED_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') AND TO_DATE('2015/01/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

The call to `trunc` makes this non-sargable and forces a complete table or index scan. It can be changed to make it more efficient (assuming the RECEIVED_DATE column is indexed).

```
where   d.received_date >= date '2015-01-01'
    and d.received_date < date '2015-02-01'
```

Use `to_date` or `date`. I prefer the latter but neither affects efficiency. Changing the second date to the first day of the next month is preferred because while every month has a day 1, not every month has a day 31, or even 30. This standardizes within-month checks.

Also in a couple of places:

```
AND Trunc(a.received_date) >= TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Again, the call to `trunc` makes it unsargable. To make matters worse (or ironic) is that it is completely unnecessary.

```
AND a.received_date >= TO_DATE('2015/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

produces exactly the same results and is sargable.

There is one place where I think you have a bug. There are two almost identical segments of code on each side of the `union all`. In each of these there are two places where the check `actioncode <> 'D'` is made. Except that in the last place, the actual check is `airlinecode <> 'D'`.

Comment: It's possible he has a function-based index on `TRUNC(whatever_date)` but your corrections are sound.

Comment: @TommCatt.  Thanks for your suggestions. Will reduce the use of `trunc` in possible places so as to make the query sargable. Currently modified the query to use only one outer join instead of two. Also eliminated some case statements. It seems to be better(not the best though) compared its previous version.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is your problem:

```
* 15 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN   | ACCRUAL_IDX7      |    58M|  1452M|   112K  (1)| 00:22:33 |
```

That's going to look through 58,000,000 keys which it says is going to take 22 minutes i.e. about 66% of the total time it thinks it's going to take. Is there any way you can limit the range of the key it needs to search?

My experience of Oracle - in fact almost any RDBMS - is that the times and row counts in a query plan are not necessarily accurate, but are correct on an order of magnitude: it might not be exactly 58M rows but it is millions, it might not be 22 minutes but it will be about 66%, and so on.

If you can't limit the values of the keys in that index, is there an alternative index the query could use? Forcing it to use that index via a hint might make a difference.

Sadly I don't think a definitive answer is possible as a) we don't have the indexes on the tables b) the meanings of the fields in the tables and c) the tables with representative data in to try things. A lot of query tuning requires these things, and is quite often guess-work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i will check for the possible indexes available on the tables which would help the query performance.